# Why an additional file is created when sending an attachment (php)

Tags: php, email

When I use my function to send a mail, an extra file ATT00001.htm is created and sent with my attachement when the code is executed. 
How can I remove it ?
It can come from the boundary but I don't arrive to find where are my mistakes.

here's the code of my function :

```
function mail_csv(){


    $to      = "to@to";
    $from    = "toto@toto";
    $subject = "Test csv";

    $separator = md5(time());

    $eol         = PHP_EOL;
    $path        = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/sites/'.get_current_blog_id().'/test_csv/';
    $filename    = "test_csv.csv";
    $attachement = file_get_contents($path.$filename);
    $attachement = chunk_split(base64_encode($attachement));

    $headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="'.$separator.'"';

    $attached  = "--" .$separator.$eol;
    $attached .= 'Content-Type: text/csv; name="'.$filename.'"'.$eol;
    $attached .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
    $attached .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"'.$eol.$eol;
    $attached .= $attachement.$eol;
    $attached .= "--".$separator."--";

    $body = "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
    $body .= "Envoi d'un mail avec un fichier .csv en pièce jointe.".$eol;

    $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
    $body .= $message.$eol.$attached.$eol;

    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        error_log("OK");
    } else {
        error_log("Erreur");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using some library? Like PHPMailer? Then you don't need to manually set all bits

Comment: No I didn't try to use PHPMailer, all the code is efficient without PHPMailer except on outlook. I would like to understand where the problem is before to try another way to do my function. Thanks for your answer